# FindResource find resource by name fails

Tags: c++, winapi

```
HRSRC test = FindResourceW(hModule, L"TEST", RT_MANIFEST);
```

FindResource fails with *ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND*. I only renamed manifest's resource name to a string and then tried to find it. I believe it has something to do with `MAKEINTRESOURCE`/`IS_INTRESOURCE` or I'm not sure at all. Any ideas? However, it worked fine when the resource was named just `1`.

> **ERROR_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND**
>
> 1814 (0x716)
>
> The specified resource name cannot be found in the image file.

[image]

**Edit:**

**1st iteration:**
[image]

**2nd iteration:**
[image]

```
struct Resource
{
    LPVOID lpData;
    LPCWSTR lpType;
    LPCWSTR lpName;
    DWORD dwSize;
};

bool EnumNamesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpType, LPWSTR lpName, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    HRSRC hResource = nullptr;

    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
    {
        hResource = FindResource(hModule, lpName, lpType);

        std::wcout << "It is not. " << lpName << std::endl;
    }
    else if (IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
    {
        hResource = FindResource(hModule, lpName, lpType);

        std::cout << "It is" << std::endl;
    }

    if (!hResource)
    {
        return false;
    }

    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);

    if (!hGlobal)
    {
        return false;
    }

    LPVOID lpResource = LockResource(hGlobal);

    if (!lpResource)
    {
        return false;
    }

    Resource temp;
    temp.lpData = hGlobal;
    temp.lpType = lpType;
    temp.lpName = lpName;
    temp.dwSize = dwSize;

    resources.push_back(temp);

    FreeResource(lpResource);

    return true;
}
```

This code is working but it leaks:

```
Resource temp;
temp.lpData = hGlobal;
temp.lpType = lpType;

if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
{
    LPVOID temp = malloc(sizeof(LPCWSTR) * wcslen(lpName));
    memcpy(temp, lpName, sizeof(LPCWSTR) * wcslen(lpName));
    temp.lpName = temp;
}
else
{
    temp.lpName = lpName;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell. Since that functionality has to work, I guess likely to be a configuration/setup issue. Like a resource only DLL has not been compiled with Unicode enabled. Are the strings that are resource names in the image file narrow? Then it won't find L"Text""

Comment: No, they aren't. The region is mapped. `LoadLibraryEx(this->fileName.c_str(), nullptr, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);`.

Comment: Ok, I know it's because of unicode but how do I solve it.

Comment: @nop You did not explain how you created the resource in the first place, or how you renamed it, or what `hModule` points to, or what `EnumResourceNames()` did (or did not) report.

Comment: @RemyLebeau. I edited it with Resource Hacker but nothing of it matters. The problem occurs for all string named resources and now I see why. If u look at the debugging image above (I just edited it), it saves some temporary address which is wrong.

Comment: @nop in your `EnumResourceNames()` callback, you can't save the raw pointers for `lpType` and `lpName` when `IS_INTRESOURCE()` returns FALSE for them. That data is gone once the callback exits, leaving your `resources` container with invalid pointers. So, in that case, you need to copy the null-terminated character data that they are pointing to.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's the problem.

Comment: the thing is that I don't know what's the best way to solve it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, can you look at the edit, thanks. I need some way which doesn't leak memory.

Comment: @nop don't use `malloc()` in C++, use `new` instead. But either way, you are not including a null-terminator in your copy. As for leaking, add a destructor to `Resource` to call `free()`/`delete` on `lpName` when `IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName)` is false (you need the same logic for `lpType` since resource types are not always numeric). Also, you need a copy assignment operator in `Resource` to deep-copy `lpType`/`lpName` correctly. Personally, I would change `Resource`'s `lpType`/`lpName` to `std::wstring`. If you get a numeric `lpType`/`lpName` value, convert it to `"#..."` format.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, how can you do that with `new`. Can you give an example

Comment: As for the null-termination, I have to do just that `(wcslen(lpName) + 1) * sizeof(LPCWSTR);`, right? @RemyLebeau

Comment: @nop Yes for +1 on the length. But you need to use `sizeof(WCHAR)` instead of `sizeof(LPCWSTR)`. See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `EnumResourceNames()` callback, you can't save the raw pointers for `lpType` and `lpName` when `IS_INTRESOURCE()` returns false for them. That data is gone once the callback exits, leaving your `resources` container with invalid pointers. So, in that case, you need to copy the null-terminated character data that they are pointing to (which you are attempting to do, but you are not doing it correctly).

To avoid leaking memory, add a destructor to `Resource` to free the `lpName`/`lpType` data when `IS_INTRESOURCE()` is false for them.  Also, you need to add a *copy constructor* and a *copy assignment operator* to `Resource` to deep-copy the `lpType`/`lpName` data correctly (per the [Rule of 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Also, your callback needs to return a `BOOL` instead of a `bool`, and it needs to use the `__stdcall` calling convention (wrapped by the `WINAPI` and `CALLBACK` macros).

Try something more like this:

```cpp
struct Resource
{
    LPWSTR lpType;
    LPWSTR lpName;
    HANDLE lpData;
    DWORD dwSize;

    Resource(LPCWSTR, LPWSTR, HANDLE, DWORD);
    Resource(const Resource &);
    ~Resource();
    Resource& operator=(const Resource &);
};
```

```cpp
LPWSTR MakeResourceCopy(LPCWSTR Value)
{
    if (IS_INTRESOURCE(Value))
        return const_cast<LPWSTR>(Value);

    int len = wcslen(Value) + 1;
    LPWSTR copy = new WCHAR[len];
    memcpy(copy, Value, sizeof(WCHAR) * len);
    return copy;
}

Resource::Resource(LPCWSTR Type, LPWSTR Name, HANDLE Data, DWORD Size)
{
    lpType = MakeResourceCopy(Type);
    lpName = MakeResourceCopy(Name);
    lpData = Data;
    dwSize = Size;
}

Resource::Resource(const Resource &src)
{
    lpType = MakeResourceCopy(src.lpType);
    lpName = MakeResourceCopy(src.lpName);
    lpData = src.lpData;
    dwSize = src.dwSize;
}

Resource::~Resource()
{
    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpType))
        delete[] lpType;

    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
        delete[] lpName;
}

Resource& Resource::operator=(const Resource &rhs)
{
    if (&rhs != this)
    {
        Resource copy(rhs);

        using std::swap;
        swap(lpType, copy.lpType);
        swap(lpName, copy.lpName);
        swap(lpData, copy.lpData);
        swap(dwSize, copy.dwSize);
    }

    return *this;
}
```

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK EnumNamesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpType, LPWSTR lpName, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpType))
        std::wcout << "lpType is not an integer. " << lpType << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lpType is an integer. #" << reinterpret_cast<int>(lpType) << std::endl;

    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
        std::wcout << "lpName is not an integer. " << lpName << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lpName is an integer. #" << reinterpret_cast<int>(lpName) << std::endl;

    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, lpName, lpType);
    if (!hResource)
        return FALSE;

    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    if (!hGlobal)
        return FALSE;

    LPVOID lpResource = LockResource(hGlobal);
    if (!lpResource)
        return FALSE;

    Resource res(lpType, lpName, hGlobal, dwSize);
    resources.push_back(res);

    return TRUE;
}
```

That said, I would suggest changing the `Resource`'s `lpType`/`lpName` fields to `std::wstring` instead.  If you get a numeric `lpType`/`lpName` value, simply convert it to `"#..."` format.  Let the compiler handle all of the memory management for you:

```cpp
struct Resource
{
    std::wstring lpType;
    std::wstring lpName;
    HANDLE lpData;
    DWORD dwSize;
};
```

```cpp
std::wstring MakeResourceWString(LPCWSTR Value)
{
    if (IS_INTRESOURCE(Value))
        return L"#" + std::to_wstring(reinterpret_cast<int>(Value));
    else
        return Value;
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumNamesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpType, LPWSTR lpName, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpType))
        std::wcout << "lpType is not an integer. " << lpType << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lpType is an integer. #" << reinterpret_cast<int>(lpType) << std::endl;

    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
        std::wcout << "lpName is not an integer. " << lpName << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lpName is an integer. #" << reinterpret_cast<int>(lpName) << std::endl;

    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, lpName, lpType);
    if (!hResource)
        return FALSE;

    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    if (!hGlobal)
        return FALSE;

    LPVOID lpResource = LockResource(hGlobal);
    if (!lpResource)
        return FALSE;

    Resource res;
    res.lpType = MakeResourceWString(lpType);
    res.lpName = MakeResourceWString(lpName);
    res.lpData = hGlobal;
    res.dwSize = dwSize;

    resources.push_back(res);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Alternatively, use `std::variant` instead:

```cpp
struct Resource
{
    std::variant<int, std::wstring> lpType;
    std::variant<int, std::wstring> lpName;
    HANDLE lpData;
    DWORD dwSize;
};
```

```cpp
std::variant<int, std::wstring> MakeResourceVariant(LPCWSTR Value)
{
    if (IS_INTRESOURCE(Value))
        return reinterpret_cast<int>(Value);
    else
        return std::wstring(Value);
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumNamesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpType, LPWSTR lpName, LONG_PTR lParam)
{
    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpType))
        std::wcout << "lpType is not an integer. " << lpType << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lpType is an integer. #" << reinterpret_cast<int>(lpType) << std::endl;

    if (!IS_INTRESOURCE(lpName))
        std::wcout << "lpName is not an integer. " << lpName << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "lpName is an integer. #" << reinterpret_cast<int>(lpName) << std::endl;

    HRSRC hResource = FindResource(hModule, lpName, lpType);
    if (!hResource)
        return FALSE;

    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(hModule, hResource);
    HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hModule, hResource);
    if (!hGlobal)
        return FALSE;

    LPVOID lpResource = LockResource(hGlobal);
    if (!lpResource)
        return FALSE;

    Resource res;
    res.lpType = MakeResourceVariant(lpType);
    res.lpName = MakeResourceVariant(lpName);
    res.lpData = hGlobal;
    res.dwSize = dwSize;

    resources.push_back(res);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your incredible answer! How do I access `variant`?

Comment: Start by [reading this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and looking at the examples provided.

Comment: Thanks, there is one problem tho. https://i.imgur.com/EVgMHLs.png I think that's because the callback is static `static bool EnumNamesFunc(HMODULE hModule, LPCWSTR lpType, LPWSTR lpName, LONG_PTR lParam);` because it's inside a class with a private access modifier.

Comment: Those errors have nothing to do with the callback itself at all. They mean you have put the implementations of the `Resource` methods in the wrong place, causing the compiler to output the definitions into every `.obj` for every `.cpp` that uses `Resource`, thus confusing the linker. My guess, you put the implementations into an `.h` file when they belong in a `.cpp` file instead

Comment: That was the reason, nice! Btw, I couldn't get the variant solution to work: https://i.imgur.com/4Gzn9Pr.png. However, the first solution works perfectly.

Comment: @nop [`std::get<0>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) in this example assumes only `int` values are ever stored, but if `std::wstring` is stored then you get the `bad_variant_access` error. You have to check the type stored in a `variant` before accessing the data, eg: `LPWSTR ToResourcePtr(std::variant<int, std::wstring> &v) { switch (v.index()) { case 0: return MAKEINTRESOURCE(std::get<0>(v)); case 1: return const_cast<LPWSTR>(std::get<1>(v).c_str()); } return nullptr; }` ... `UpdateResource(..., ToResourcePtr(resouce.lpType), ToResourcePtr(resouce.lpName), ...);`